# Why is my session variable being lost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am having an issue with my session variables. I am adding objects to session, so that when i navigate to the next page (building a sort of questionnaire) i can retrieve these values in another Controller action, and use the stored value to make some calculations.

It is also said that this functionality is used for the user to go backwards through the questionnaire, should they wish to change an input to get a different outcome. However upon going backwards, the variables are gone, and my  controller action code fails and brings back a null reference exception.

Any thoughts on why this is doing this? I am adding the the variable to session using following way:

```
Session["UserInfo"] = myObject;
```

and retrieving like so

```
InputData data = (InputData) Session["UserInfo"];
```

any reasons why i'm losing these objects. If i go back and click submit again , they're back in session and usable on the following page. I don't think this is a session timeout issue as i do it well within 20mins, usually like 30secs (as i'm developing the system and testing and making changes etc.)

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6305647/181087)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this, my issue was the GET and POST requests on my action controllers. I was not specifying two controller actions explicitly (HTTPGET and HTTPPOST) so all requests going to the same action, and therefore was over-riding the session variable with NULL as nothing was being posted, as a ajax get request.

Setup up two action results HTTP POST and HTTP GET one with input parameters and the other without. Never crossed my mind, until had a cup of coffee and a fresh brain.