# mvcrazortopdf Null Reference Exception on first click ASP.NEt (Session not retrieving properly)

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvcrazortopdf

Im working on a program that downloads a pdf file using mvcrazortopdf. On the first click, it throws a `NullReferenceException` error. Here is my code:

Controller:(ReviewerController.cs)

```
    public ActionResult PicOrderPDF() //error on this line
    {
        PurchaseOrder req = (PurchaseOrder)Session["purchaseOrderData"];
        var date = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Now);

        return new PdfActionResult(req)
        {
            FileDownloadName = date + "-PurchaseOrder" + (req.PicID).ToString("D4") + ".pdf"
        };

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadPdf(PurchaseOrder purchaseOrder)
    {
        Session["purchaseOrderData"] = purchaseOrder;
        return RedirectToAction("PicOrderPDF", "Reviewer");

    }
```

Model: (PurchaseOrder.cs)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SampleProject.Models
{
    public class PurchaseOrder : Account
    {

       public int PicID { get; set; }
       public DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

PicOrderPDF is the view of the pdf to be downloaded. I tried adding a breakpoint at the error line to check and turns out req is null.But after continuing and clicking download again, it downloads just fine. Sorry im new at this

Comment: Is `req` null because there isn't any session item called `purchaseOrderData`?

Comment: Try to retrieve purchaseOrder from session just after adding it to session in DownloadPdf action and check if it is null?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya should i retrieve it in DownloadPdf or in PicOrderPDF?

Comment: @desperateStudent you mean when you go directly  to PicOrderPDF it throws exception or when you go from DownloadPdf?

Comment: @Usman the null exception is on the PicOrderPDF particularly in the `PdfActionResult`

Comment: When you go to picorderpdf before download pdf it will throw exception because the session will be null

Comment: @Usman sorry im new to this. Would you suggest removing the `[HttpPost]` and go to `DownloadPDF`first then `PicOrderPDF`

Comment: you are sending purchase order from the view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144107/discussion-between-usman-and-desperatestudent).

Comment: @Usman sent downloadpdf funtion in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was the first time the session was cleared which resolved with adding

```
protected void Session_Start()
 {

 }
```

in the `Global.asax.cs` you can also check this [session variables lost between controllers action methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844635/session-variables-lost-between-controllers-action-methods)

Comment: "Server Error in '/' Application."

Comment: Are you sure `req` is not null ?

Comment: OMG it worked, Thank you @Usman!!